# therubyracer (0.8.0) error on Ubuntu/Linux 11.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, bundle

I am running the latest version of RVM on Ubuntu/Linux 11.10. I just tried installing a project in it's own gem set using rvm use 1.9.2@the_project --create. Then I ran gem install bundler;bundle install and got the following error.

I have had this error before, I have tried sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential but had no luck. I also tried installing libv8-3.1.8.22 libv8-dbg libv8-dev and still had no luck. Could this be related to Ubuntu 11.10? Does anyone have any suggestions?

The error: https://gist.github.com/1340929 (was too long to post)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is actually an issue with v8 and gcc 4.6:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium-os/issues/detail?id=17886

Answer (score -1):

With RVM, there is much more than just `build-essential` that you need to properly compile gems. Run `rvm requirements` (but if that doesn't work, you may be on an older RVM and should do `rvm notes` instead) and install *everything* that it tells you to. The list will be something like this:

`apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion`

I just compiled therubyracer in 11.10 tonight and it worked fine.

Comment: I already had all of this install...so it seems. I still get the error.